# jQuery - Creating a slider to rate something

Tags: jquery, slider

I am creating a Web page using jQuery and I want users to rate a value. For example, I ask them to rate their knowledge of something through a number between 0 and 1. I want to do this using a slider, namely an object with a lever that the user can move.
I have tried the library in

http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/

It is wonderful, but I need more control on the slider, for example I want to position it wherever I want within the page. Moreover, I'd like to attach two labels to its endings: "very bad" and "very good". I don't understand how to do this using this slider library because I would need to modify the code of the library itself.

Is there another way to obtain such a slider without using this library? Searching on the Web for jQuery slider I find things related to sliding images.

Comment: check this demo 
[link](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/10/07/slider-gallery/)

Comment: The simple-slider is just a plugin, you can place it anywhere, add text anywhere etc. it's just basic html and css, and then a few lines to get the slider working ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [this](http://egorkhmelev.github.io/jslider/) jQuery slider plugin. It has more features than the average jQuery UI widget.

Answer (score 0):

This [jQuery Bar Rating](http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/) is very good, it tranform select field into rating widget.

**HTML**

```
<select id="example">
 <option value="1">Very bad</option>
 <option value="2"></option>
 <option value="3"></option>
 <option value="4"></option>
 <option value="5">Very good</option>
</select>
```

**Script**

```
 $('#example').barrating({
    theme: 'name-theme'
  });
```